# A regular tetrahedron is centered at the origin with vertices $ (0,0,1$) and $(a,0,b)$.

Tags: geometry, solid-geometry

All of its vertices satisfy $x^2+y^2+z^2=1$
Find the remaining two vertices with respect to $a$ and $b$.

Comment: I attempted to draw said vertices but I am getting caught up with what do we mean exactly by the figure centered at the origin

Comment: The vertices are centered at the origin, so a start is to note that $a^2+b^2=1.$ Then you can use dot product to relate angles between the vectors to the vertices from the origin, once you figure what those angles should be.

Comment: user338365 By centered at the origin it means all vertices are on the sphere of radius $1$ centered at $(0,0,0).$

Comment: Is there anyway to do this with using dot product?

Comment: I haven't had calc 3 in about 3 years

Comment: There may be a way but I don't know it immediately. It would have to be some operation which, given two vectors u,v from the origin of length 1, produced another one w such that the angles between any two of the three u,v,w are the same.

Comment: @user338365 Regarding the center see image 5 of my answer.

Comment: Since $a^2+b^2=1$ Let $a = p  \cos \alpha ,\, b= p \sin \alpha$. So it may be a better  posed question if you asked to find $p, \alpha $ in $( p  \cos \alpha ,\, p  \sin \alpha,0) $  for the  projection  instead   of ( a,0,b).

Comment: In which case $p=2 \sqrt2/3 $etc., $ \alpha $ is arbitrary ,easy to evaluate.

Answer (score 2):

To solve everything from scratch will result in a too long answer,
so we assume these important properties to be known:

[image: Tetraeder in cube construction]

**Image 1:** Tetraeder in cube construction. ([Source](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Datei:W%C3%9CRFELA_Tetraederwinkel.PNG))

1. The tetraeder in the task has the internal arm length $1$, meaning
   the distance from origin to top vertex. Then the edge length between
   two vertices is $L=2\sqrt{2/3}$.
   (This corresponds to a cube length $s=2/\sqrt{3}$ in the above image)
2. The internal angle between two arms is $\theta\approx 109^0$ with
   $\arccos \theta = -1/3$.
   (This is only used to check the following results)

For the second vertex $Q=(a,0,b)$ we have the constraints that it lies on the unit sphere around the origin and on the sphere around $P=(0,0,1)$ of radius $L$.
\begin{align}
1 &= x^2 + y^2 + z^2 \\
L^2 &= x^2 + y^2 + (z-1)^2
\end{align}
The intersection is the circle at height
$$
L^2 = 2-2 z \iff z = 1 - L^2/2 = 1-4/3 = -1/3
$$
with the equation
$$
x^2+y^2=1-1/9=(2\sqrt{2}/3)^2 \quad (*)
$$
which has radius $r = 2 \sqrt{2}/3$.

[image: Constraints for $Q$.]
([Large version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bbguL.jpg))

**Image 2:** Unit sphere constraint (red), $L$ sphere constraint (green). plane constraints $z=-1/3$ and $y = 0$.

Cut with the plane $y=0$ this leaves two choices:
$$
Q=\left( \pm2\sqrt{2}/3,0,-1/3 \right)
$$
Note that we can pick only one of these solutions and not both as feasible vertices, as the angle between them is not $\theta$. 
We continue with the positive choice $Q_1$.

The constraints for $P$ and $A$ again lead to two choices for the third vertex $R$:

[image: Unit sphere and two L sphere constraints]
[image: Unit sphere and two L sphere constraints]
([Large version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vSPhP.jpg) left image) ([Large version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6HZPF.jpg) right image)

**Images 3 and 4:** Unit sphere (purple) and $L$ sphere constraints for $P$ (red) and $Q$ (green). Intersection circles (yellow).

The intersection of unit sphere and $L$ sphere of $Q$
$$
1 = x^2 + y^2 +z^2 \\
L^2 = (x-2\sqrt{2}/3)^2 + y^2 + (z+1/3)^2
$$
gives
$$
L^2 = 8/3 = 1 -(4\sqrt{2}/3)x + 8/9 + (2/3)z + 1/9 \iff \\
1 = - 2\sqrt{2}x + z
$$
as equation of the plane where the intersection circle lies in.

Intersecting this plane with circle $(*)$ we get the equations
$$
1 = -2\sqrt{2} x -1/3 \iff
x = -\sqrt{2}/3
$$
and
$$
8/9 = 2/9 + y^2 \iff y = \pm \sqrt{6}/3
$$
which gives two feasible vertices
$$
R = (-\sqrt{2}/3, \pm \sqrt{6}/3, -1/3)
$$
It turns out that these are the remaing two vertices we are looking for.

[image: Resulting tetraeder]
([Large version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z7kfQ.jpg))

**Image 5:** The resulting tetraeder $(P,Q_1, R_1, R_2)$. Note the two measured tetraeder angles $\theta$. Note the alternative tetraeder vertex $Q_2$.

**Summary:**

We found two tetraeder that fit the task.
$$
\begin{array}{l}
P = \left( 0, 0, 1 \right) \\
Q_1 = \left( 2\sqrt{2}/3,0,-1/3 \right) \\
R_! = \left( -\sqrt{2}/3, \sqrt{6}/3, -1/3 \right) \\
R_2 = \left( -\sqrt{2}/3, -\sqrt{6}/3, -1/3 \right)
\end{array}
\quad\quad
\begin{array}{l}
P = \left( 0, 0, 1 \right) \\
Q_2 = \left( -2\sqrt{2}/3,0,-1/3 \right) \\
R_3 = \left( \sqrt{2}/3, \sqrt{6}/3, -1/3 \right) \\
R_4 = \left( \sqrt{2}/3, -\sqrt{6}/3, -1/3 \right)
\end{array}
$$

Answer (score 2):

Let $c=\dfrac{\sqrt{2}}{3}$, $d=\dfrac{\sqrt{2}}{\sqrt{3}}$

With these notations, the solution is:

$A_1(0,0,1)$ (given), $A_2(2c,0,-1/3)$, $A_3(-c,d,-1/3)$ and $A_4(-c,-d,-1/3)$

The way I have done it:

1) As the center of mass is necessarily the origin, knowing that a regular tetrahedron has its center of mass at the $1/4$ of its height, points $A_2, A_3, A_4$ constituting the (horizontal) base of the tetrahedron must all have their $z$ coordinate equal to -1/3.
In particular $b=-1/3$.

2) Obtaining $a$: because of the sphere constraint $a^2+0^2+(1/3)^2=1$, we have $a=2c$.

3) Obtaining edge length (squared) : Knowing now the coordinates $A_1$ and $A_2$, the value of the **square** of the length of any edge is $(A_1A_2)^2=8/3$.

4) Let $A_3=(e,f,-1/3)$ and $A_4(g,h,-1/3)$. Then "sphere constraints" give 
$e^2+f^2+1/9=1 \ \ (1)$ and $g^2+h^2+1/9=1 \ \ (2)$.

5) Edge lengths constraints (as seen before) i.e., $(A_1A_3)^2=8/3$ and $(A_1A_4)^2=8/3$ give equations $(e-1)^2+f^2+1/9=8/3  \ \ (3)$ and $(g-1)^2+h^2+1/9=8/3 \ \ (4)$.

6) Using equations (1), (2), (3), (4) the four unknowns $e,f,g,h$ are easily obtained.

**Remark:** if you know rotation matrices, after items 1) and 2) one can proceed to a computation that applies the following rotation matrix (axis $0z$, angle $2 \pi/3$) twice to vector $\vec{OA_2}=\begin{bmatrix}2\sqrt{2}/3\\0\\-1/3\end{bmatrix}$:

$$R=\begin{bmatrix}-1/2& -\sqrt{3}/2& 0\\\sqrt{3}/2& -1/2& 0\\0& 0& 1\end{bmatrix}$$

Comment: @mvw No, there is no such degree of freedom ; the only thing we can say is that we could have taken $a$ with the opposite sign... All this because the angle between $\vec{OA_0}$ and $\vec{OA_1}$ has to be precisely $acos(-1/3)$ (the 109 degrees between hydrogen atoms that many chemists know in the tetrahedron $CH_4$)

Comment: @mvw Sorry but no again, if you take say $a \approx 0.99$ and $b \approx 0.14$, you would have $a^2+b^2=1$ and a point $A_2$ very close to point $A_1$...